# Is there a way to make ToEnum generic

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I would like to do this but it does not work.

```
bool TryGetEnum<TEnum, TValue>(TValue value, out TEnum myEnum)
{

    value = default(TEnum);
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), value))
    {
        myEnum = (TEnum)value;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example usage:

```
MyEnum mye;
bool success = this.TryGetEnum<MyEnum,char>('c',out mye);
```

Comment: I'm not sure this makes much sense...if you updated including a use-case there may be an easy implementation for it.

Comment: *why* doesn't it work? what errors do you get? :D

Comment: Cannot convert type 'TValue' to 'TEnum'

Comment: Something like http://www.objectreference.net/post/Enum-TryParse-Extension-Method.aspx ?

Comment: How could you ever cast  `'c'` to an enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
myEnum = (TEnum)((object)value);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best you will be able to do is this:

```
bool TryGetEnum<TEnum>(Object value, out TEnum myEnum)
{
    myEnum = default(TEnum);
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), value))
    {
        myEnum = (TEnum)value;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

With a use case that looks something like this:

```
MyEnum mye;
bool success = this.TryGetEnum<MyEnum>(2, out mye);
```

You won't be able to make the input type generic as there are no generic constraints available for you to leverage that would enable you to guarantee that `TEnum` uses `TValue` as its underlying type.

Also, (as a side note) C# only allows the following types to be used as the underlying value for an `enum`:

> - `byte`
> - `sbyte`
> - `short`
> - `ushort`
> - `int`
> - `uint`
> - `long`
> - `ulong`